# Can Keynote on iOS play PowerPoint files with audio?

Tags: ipad, ios, keynote, ms-office

I have a family member who's considering buying an iPad. The biggest needs she has is to see PowerPoint presentations with music/audio.

She currently has an iMac with Microsoft Office installed, and thus she can read 99% of the PowerPoint ppt/pptx file. I fear that the iPad might not be able to play any presentation's music.

How can this be done on the iPad? If this requires an app to be purchased, that's OK.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently just put a presentation together which had music and a video and it played the same as on the computer using [Keynote](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote/id361285480?mt=8). There is another app (which I have not used) which might work better and be the first thing to try (it's free): [Slide Shark](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slideshark-powerpoint-presentations/id471369684?mt=8).

Comment: Slide Shark does not play music. I just installed it and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't bought Keynote yet, there are other ways to show PowerPoint presentation with embedded audios - save powerpoint as quicktime movie.

1. Click “File” on the ribbon and choose “Save as Movie” in the drop-down menu.
2. In the pop up window, type in the file name and select a destination folder for the output movie. Click the “Movie Options” button near the bottom.
3. In the “Movie Settings” tab, choose an “Optimization” from the pop-up menu. The following options are offered: Size, Smooth Playback, Quality, and Automatic (Normal).
4. The default movie size is 640 x 480; you can change it if you wish.
5. In the “Slide Transitions” pop-up menu, choose either “Follow Slide Show Settings” retain the transitions you applied in the original PowerPoint document or “None” to eliminate all transitions.
6. If you want to add music or narration to your movie, choose “Select Soundtrack” from the “Background Soundtrack” pop-up menu and then choose an audio file to serve as your movie’s soundtrack.
   Click the “Loop Movie” check box if you want the movie to play over and over again.
7. Click the “Show Movie Player Controls” check box if you want the receiver to be able to start, stop, and pause the movie.
8. Click the “OK” button to apply the settings.

**Notes**: The animation effects of the original PowerPoint file is not saved in the QuickTime movie.